# Conditionals in \newcommand

Tags: macros, conditionals

I find myself using the `\newcommand` macro a lot and apart from having the occasional difficulty with properly defining the optional parameter the macro works well. There is one serious limitation though, which I hope will show itself as being my ignorance rather than a limitation, namely the ability to make the macro definition subject to the particular value of a parameter. A simple example: I find frequent use of the expression {1, 2, ..., n} what I call an n-set and am using the following simple macro:

```
\newcommand{\myNset}{\{1,2,\dots,n\}}
```

Wouldn't it be helpful if I could pass an integer as parameter, make `n` its default, and produce {1,2} or {1,2,3) etc. if the parameter happens to be 2 or 3. Certainly beats the clumsy:

```
\newcommand{\myTwoset}{\{1,2\}}
\newcommand{\myThreeset}{\{1,2,3\}}
```

etc., which of course is too clumsy to be of use. Where draw the line?, at 10?, at 27?

This may only be a trivial example, but I find applications for such conditional processing of my `\newcommand` macros time and time again, for instance in connection with creating matrices. It would take my use of LaTeX to whole new level.

By the way, I have read through the relevant pages in the LaTeX Companion, but no luck.

Comment: Thanks Werner, still coming to grips with texting in questions, comments, answers. I now know how to put code in a block, but how would I have put that \newcommand inline?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\myNset[1][99]{\{1,2\ifnum#1=3 ,3\else\ifnum#1>3 ,\dots,n\fi\fi\}}

\begin{document}

\myNset
\myNset[3]
\myNset[2]

\end{document}
```

`\myNset[0]` and `[1]` are the same as `[2]`

Comment: Thanks, that works, and I am experimenting with it. Evidently I should have consulted the LaTeX Companion on control structures, and it goes without saying that all those structures can then be used in \newcommand definitions. Can they?

Comment: sure, no problem

Comment: Herbert, I am impressed with that logo in your profile. Any chance of letting me have the source code for that?

Comment: it can be found at the 3d gallery of http://PSTricks.tug.org

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping it is TikZ, but psTricks I will get around to eventually.

Answer (score 18):

With this LaTeX3 implementation, the optional argument can be also a variable:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\Nset}{O{n}}
  {
   \{1
   \str_case:nnF { #1 }
     {
      {1} {}
      {2} {,2}
      {3} {,2,3}
      {4} {,2,3,4}
     }
     {,2,\dots,#1}
   \}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
$\Nset$

$\Nset[1]$

$\Nset[2]$

$\Nset[3]$

$\Nset[4]$

$\Nset[5]$

$\Nset[m]$

$\Nset[k-1]$
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `\NewDocumentCommand{\Nset}{O{n}}{...}` we define a command having a unique optional argument, with default value `n`. This command typesets a left brace and `1`, then examines the argument checking against a list of known values, in this case 1, 2, 3 and 4, taking the appropriate action (i.e., typesetting all the numbers missing to the argument, separated by commas); if the optional argument doesn't appear in the list the last action is performed, that is, typesetting `,2,\dots,<argument>`. Finally, the closing brace is found.

Comment: Thank you, that works. I was completely unaware that I have access to LaTeX3, thought I was working with LaTeX2 only. Where do I read up on this stuff? It looks very promising, but I am completely unfamiliar with the syntax. For example I am having a merry time getting the macro put {} around my n-sets.

Comment: @ReinhardNeuwirth `texdoc expl3` and `texdoc interface3`. I'll fix the braces, sorry. :)

Comment: (1) Now that you fixed the braces I too can see where they had to go! (2) You are way ahead of me, how do I get access to texdoc exp13 and interface3? All documemts I find are varieties of LaTeX2. (3) I intend to give Herbert the benefit of having answered my question. He got me on the right track and I have spent the last hour fixing up large numbers of newcommands and it is therefore proper to give him credit for that. Is there a way to give you credit for launching me into the wonderful world of LaTeX3? Your answer works, even if I don't yet know how to write similar stuff myself.

Comment: The `texdoc` command is a shell command. It depends on the OS you're using how to issue it; for example, TeXShop has a menu entry to access `texdoc`. On other systems or with other front-ends it's different. An upvote if the answer is deemed useful is sufficient; please, accept Herbert's answer.

Comment: I am using Windows7 and TeXMaker 3.3.1 front-ending MiKTeX 2.9

Comment: @ReinhardNeuwirth In Texmaker for Mac OS X there's a help menu that contains a `texdoc` entry. It should be there also on the other supported platforms.

Comment: Found it. It's all there in my MiKTeX distribution. This is leading edge stuff, looking at the release dates. No wonder I did not find any of that on my own. Your answer has led me to gold mine, thanks. Please advise urgently how I upvote you. I am struggling with the ins and outs of stack exchange.

Comment: As of today the function is `\str_case:nn`, i.e., one `n` less at the end :).

Comment: @Py_Dream Thanks, I updated.

Comment: @egreg Super! What is the F at the end for? Could you please refer me to a good tutorial/ reference material on L3? I have started out on this, but most sources including the documentation are either too cryptic or quite patchy, at least for a newcomer. Thanks.

Comment: @Py_Dream The F denotes a standard braced argument, but it emphasizes the fact that it is used when a “false” branch is taken, in this case no match of the first argument with the case list in the second argument.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution based on *catoptions* package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catoptions}
\newcommand*\Nset[1][1]{%
  \{1%
  \cptifcasse\ifstrcmpTF{#1}
    {1}{}
    {2}{, 2}
    {3}{, 2, 3}
    {4}{, 2, 3, 4}
  \elseif
    , 2, \dots, #1%
  \endif
  \}%
}

\begin{document}
$\Nset$
\par
$\Nset[1]$
\par
$\Nset[3]$
\par
$\Nset[n]$
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `\cptifcasse` command is not documented.

Comment: @egreg: Unfortunately, less than one-half of the commands in the *catoptions* package are documented. I have to pay bills outside TeX.